# timeout interval between receiving a message and acknowledging it

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

What is the timeout interval ( between receiving a message and acknowledging it ) if we are using ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE and can we configure it?

The Spring Code for queue is

ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory = new    ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(amqConnectionFactory);
    ActiveMQQueue activeMQQueue = new ActiveMQQueue("CR.DEFAULT.QUEUE");
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(activeMQQueue);
    jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(JmsDestinationAccessor.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT);

Comment: Can you provide the code for your current spring (jms connection) configuration file ?

Comment: Just update your question, that code in the comment is just bad.